# Image Intervention in Laravel store method

Tags: image, laravel, intervention

I want to loop through my request, get any uploaded images, run them through Image/Intervention to crop them down to 650 x 450 and reduce them to 90% quality and then store them.

I am currently storing my image like so:

```
$steps = $request->steps;
    $stepImages = $request->steps_img;

    foreach ( $steps as $key => $value ) {

        $newStep = new Step();

        $newStep->project_id = $project->id;
        $newStep->step_number = $key;
        $newStep->content = $value;

        if ( isset( $stepImages[$key] ) ) {

            $currentStepImage = $request->file('steps_img.' . $key )->store('steps');

            $newStep->image = $currentStepImage;

        }

        $newStep->save();

    }
```

Is it possible for me to do this at this stage? And if so, how would I go about it?